# Unexpected behavior while measuring download time using okhttp eventListener on Android

Tags: retrofit2, okhttp

This question is a continuation of https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/6991

I hope everyone is fine. I'm using `okhttp` version `4.3.1`. I'm trying to measure the download time for a file. For that I have used the following code:

```
val okHttpClientBuilder = OkHttpClient.Builder()
                .connectTimeout(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES) // connect timeout
                .writeTimeout(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES) // write timeout
                .readTimeout(5, TimeUnit.MINUTES)

                .eventListener(object : EventListener() {
                    override fun callStart(call: Call) {
                        val callTimeEnd = System.currentTimeMillis()
                        Log.v(TAG, "callTimeEnd: $callTimeEnd")
                    }

                    override fun callEnd(call: Call) {
                        val callTimeStart = System.currentTimeMillis()
                        Log.v(TAG, "callTimeEnd: $callTimeEnd")
                    }
                })
```

It logged the following timestamps:

**callStart:** 1641622023750

**callEnd:**  1641622031159

and `callEnd` - `callStart` = `~7.4seconds`. My device (Android 9.0) has downloading speed of `5 Mega bits per second`. File size is `25 Mega Bytes`. Ideally, downloading time should be `~40 seconds`. Am I missing something or do the library is doing something under the hood?

Moreover, another device (`Android 8.0`) with downloading speed of `20 Mega bits per second` is downloading the same file in `~ 10 seconds` i.e., taking longer time than `Android 9.0` device. Any pointer will be appreciated.

Comment: @Yuri Schimke: I have recorded bytes in `onResponseBodyEnd`, it also shows `25.1 MB`

Comment: I think the only suggestion I can offer is logging the responseBodyEnd which has a byteCount for the (possibly compressed) body.

Comment: @YuriSchimke: As I mentioned earliery, byteCount shows 25.1 MB and my net speed is 5Mbps. Why it downloads in ~4-5 seconds? I couldn't still figure out. What should I look into?

Comment: Make sure it's really connecting to the network, not using a cached result (which is exposed in the event listener).  You can also look at the compression via the headers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue was with the network to which the devices were connected. I had applied rate limits on `WAN` ports, but the server was connected to a router through `ethernet` and clients were connected via `Wifi`, therefore, the file was being served to clients using `local network` which operates on a high bandwidth i.e., router was operating on a `150 Mbps`, slow mobile was `65 Mbps`, and fast was `144 Mbps` which turns out the time to download for slow and fast was `~5 seconds` and `~3 seconds` respectively. I moved the server to `WAN` port and it provided the desired results i.e., slow device `rate limit` set to `5 Mbps` and it downloaded the `25 Mega bytes` file in `~43 seconds`.

Comment: A big sincere thanks for updating here, after you resolved this. For future, we can recommend people compare the networks and/or routes, which are available via the connection socket.  Thanks!